# Fluent NHibernate Deleting multiple objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a method to delete multiple records with Fluent NHibernate?

I now use this method to delete multiple records

```
Session.Delete(string.Format("from {0} o where o.RecordCreatedTime > {1}", 
                              typeof(Order).Name + "s",
                              DateTime.NowUTC.Date.AddDays(-31)));
```

I am looking for something like this in Fluent

```
Session.Deleted<Order>(o => o.RecordCreatedTime >  DateTime.NowUTC.Date.AddDays(-31));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way how to Delete more items other then passing HQL. Check it here:

- [public sealed class SessionImpl : AbstractSessionImpl...](https://github.com/juanplopes/nhibernate/blob/master/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Impl/SessionImpl.cs#L725)

There are 3 overloads taking a HQL query

```
public int Delete(string query)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        return Delete(query, NoArgs, NoTypes);
    }
}

public int Delete(string query, object value, IType type)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        return Delete(query, new[] {value}, new[] {type});
    }
}
```

these two above just call this one:

```
public int Delete(string query, object[] values, IType[] types)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("query", "attempt to perform delete-by-query with null query");
        }

        CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus();

        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
        {
            log.Debug("delete: " + query);
            if (values.Length != 0)
            {
                log.Debug("parameters: " + StringHelper.ToString(values));
            }
        }

        IList list = Find(query, values, types);
        int count = list.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Delete(list[i]);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

All of them in fact resulting in a `Find()` and iterating over it.

**SOLUTION**: we can create some custom implementation... taking `ICriteria` or `QueryOver`... and iterate as well